While getting the data from service broker messages which is faster OPENXML or XML.NODES?
When I am running this from SSMS I am getting less elapsed time for XML.Nodes but looking at the  actual plan I can see less sql bucks for OPENXML. Speed is a demand if I can save in milliseconds I will go for that solution.
Here is my Plan :https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkmMHDREC

Please race your own horses.

You should largely ignore the subtree costs shown for XML operators because these are just guesses without any knowledge of how large or complex the XML will actually turn out to be in practice

If you're looking for speed, i guess less elapsed time is good? From my experience, OPENXML is only worth it when you have really large documents (in mbs)

Microsoft proprietary OPENXML() and its companions sp_xml_preparedocument and sp_xml_removedocument are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.
Also, OPENXML() cannot take advantage of XML indexes while XQuery methods can.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

The CPU and wait stats are in the actual execution plan XML.
insert into #documentopenxml ... FROM OPENXML (@hndl,N'documentxml//',1):
            <WaitStats>
              <Wait WaitType="OLEDB" WaitTimeMs="14" WaitCount="1002" />
            </WaitStats>
            <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="104" ElapsedTime="104" />

insert into #document ... @message.nodes('//SyncRecord') tbl(col):
            <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="5" ElapsedTime="5" />

And don't use //SyncRecord.  Explictly path down to the node, eg /documentxml/SyncRecord
And a Service Broker message body is varbinary(max), so you should test both methods with that, instead of starting with an XML type.
